# Express Checkout with Paypal Payflow Pro - hosted pages

Tags: paypal, express-checkout, payflowpro

According to this https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/#configuring-hosted-pages-using-paypal-manager i should be able to enable express checkout payment option on my paypal manager account(test mode) but I can't see any PayPal Express Checkout section on the Hosted Pages setup page. During the transaction i can see only credit card payment method on the hosted page. How to enable express checkout payment method?

Thanks in advance,
Daniel

Comment: You need to contact the Payflow support to add the PayPal as the processor on your manager account .Once its added you will see those option on your set up page.

Answer (score 0):

Which layout did you choose?  I'm pretty sure you have to use Layout C in order to get the Express Checkout option built in, and you need to make sure it's activated in your PayPal Manager.

Comment: I'm using layout C. And i can't see anywhere on PayPal manager any option to enable express checkout(there's no section Express Checkout on Hosted Pages Setup page as it is in docs). Maybe it's because i have only test account (didn't activate account yet). I've submitted a support ticket for that question but no answer yet.